# Substitution in functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

When solving functional equations it can be helpful to substitute another function, say, *g(x)* rather than *x* to the original functional equation *h(x)*. Under what condition is this a permissible substitution that leaves the original solution intact? Is bijectivity sufficient and if so, why is it?

Example: *h(1-h(x))=x*. Can I substitute *g(x)* for *x* in this equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please give some context (see [Get answers to practical, detailed questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Answer (score 2):

Any substitution is possible whenever the necessary assumptions are fulfilled. They are often helpful to simplify the equation in question. Let $h\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Put $1-h(x)$ instead of $x$. Hence $h(1-x)=1-h(x)$, so $$h(x)+h(1-x)=1,$$ which, maybe, maynot, allows us to gain some extra properties of the solution. For instance, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ we get $h\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)=\frac{1}{2}.$ This is not so visible by the original equation.

Comment: Thank you. But is _h(x) + h(1-x) = 1_ equivalent to the original equaition and if so, why is it? Because then I could make further elaboartions on the newly derived expression without losing information.

Comment: I assumed that $h$ is a solution. This is an implication only. For example, the identity map fulfils the equation of mine, but this is not a solution of the original equation. Nevertheless, the addditional knowledge of a solution could be derived from here. This is a necessary condition. If you collect enough information, you could check whether or not the function you arrived at is a solution of the original equation.

Comment: Does this mean that any solution of the original function must also satisfy your function? And why is this?

Comment: Does this mean that all solutions to the original function must satisfy your function? I must determine the values of the sum = f(-100) + f(-99) ... + f(100) + f(101) for all possible f which would lead to all sums being equal to 101 as the rest would cancel out

Comment: The first question is whether there exists a function satisfying the original equation. Next, if we suppose there is such function, you are right, with my equation (implied by the original one) your task is trivial. Now we have what follows: if $f$ fulfils the original equation, then the sum in question is $101$.

Comment: Thank you - makes it much clearer. So I need not assume _f_ to be bijective since your equation is a direct implication of the original one? (Sorry, I`m new to functional equations and must formalize my answer)

Comment: Yes, you are right. And don't be sorry because we, a bit more experienced colleagues, are there to help you because we love maths.

Comment: Thank you so much -